# Google-calendar api, Source.link is not viewable on guest's calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I've created an event with the Source field, as in the API:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

On the owner's calendar, I can see the "Source" field with title and url. However, on the invitee's calendar, there's none. Those screenshots are attached.
How do I enable the source for the invitee? Or is this a bug in google calendar api

Thanks.
Tung.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Only the creator can see it.

According to https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#source it is "Accessible only by the creator of the event."