# Calendar Event source title and URL

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar

A Google Calendar Event synced from a 3rd party service (e.g. Podio) often contains a plain-text link to itself in its description and also a `source` field with the hyperlink (see the screenshot).

**I can't seem to figure out how to include this `source` field when creating new event using Google Apps Script.**

In Google Calendar API, it is possible: [Google-calendar api, Source.link is not viewable on guest's calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22802691/google-calendar-api-source-link-is-not-viewable-on-guests-calendar). How about in Google Apps Script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object), https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event?

[image: Google Calendar Event Source Field]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. This will help the Stack Overflow community by clarifying the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (currently) can not add the Source link using the CalendarApp service, however you can add the Source link if you create the event using the Advanced Calendar service which must be specifically enabled in your Apps Script & on your Google Developers Console.

See:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#request-body